# How Would I Nomalize Cable TV Volume Between Commercials and Programming

Tags: audio, operational-amplifier

I have had it with commercials on cable TV being a lot louder than the program I happen to be watching. I have also had the reverse where the program switches scenes and you cannot make out what the whispering actress is saying.

I know products are already on the market that take care of this problem, but I thought it would be fun to fix it myself. I come from the microprocessor/digital side of things so I really have not played with audio a whole lot.

I current use RCA audio cables between my cable box and sound system. I would like to plug my device between those two devices so that my amplifier receives the modified normalized audio signal.

So far I have been looking at Automatic Gain Control circuits as a solution. Is this the right way to go or should I be looking at something else?

If possible, please include links to schematics, components, etc with your post. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Pretty much all sound compression filters I've seen were digital. I suppose you could ADC->DSP->DAC it (x2 for stereo) but there must be a simpler analog way. I'll be keeping an eye on this question with keen interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical electroacoustic systems use [compressors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_range_compression) (and variants - [limiters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limiter) and [levelers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leveler)) for exactly that - controlling the dynamic range of the signal. Those devices are used in audio production, by musicians, or e.g. to limit the modulation depth of a radio transmitter. Analogue compressors are still in wide use (I'd even say analogue compressors are more common in professional recording studios, not to mention vacuum tube ones).

What you need is basically a limiter or leveler, googling around for 'audio limiter schematics' yields a lot of results, I'd start the research from there. E.g. [this one](http://www.repeater-builder.com/projects/limiter.html) looks reasonably simple. There are also many circuits like [this one](http://www.seekic.com/forum/22_circuit_diagram/15583_AUDIO_LEVELER.html), based on NE577 or NE572 or similar compander chips.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The big issue with commercials aren't their peak volume.

Advertisers use [tricky techniques](http://www.ehow.com/about_6531457_tv-commercials-loud_.html) to keep the overall peak below the prescribed legal limit, but the quiet spots are boosted so that the whole commercial stays near peak.

Whatever circuit you're going to build may have to calculate an average volume over a certain time interval to be able to detect a commercial (or an excessively loud TV scene) and attenuate accordingly.